# Unity C# dialogue system script displays only first letter of public var

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a pretty strange problem. I was coding a simple dialogue system, for now it will only display a letter every 0.1 seconds.
I have a TextMeshPro text that contains the text to be displayed.
Here is attached my **DialogueLine.cs** script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

namespace DialogueSystem
{
    public class DialogueLine : DialogueBaseClass
    {
        private TextMeshProUGUI textHolder;

        [Header ("Text Options")]
        [SerializeField] private string input;

        private void Awake()
        {
            textHolder = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();

            StartCoroutine(WriteText(input, textHolder));
        }
    }
}
```

it gets the value of my "input" variable, setted from Unity interface. The script calls the "WriteText" coroutine, in the **DialogueBaseClass.cs** script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogueBaseClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected IEnumerator WriteText(string input, TextMeshProUGUI textHolder)
    {
        for (int i= 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            textHolder.text += input[i];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }
    }
}
```

A pretty simple script that adds on my "textHeader" component a letter from the input every 0.1 seconds.

But, here is the problem. **The output of my component is only the first letter of the input variable**: if in the input I write "Hello" it displays "H".

I really can't find the problem in this script...

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Maybe the routine works just fine but your text component is too small to fit the text in? And have you tried moving this to `Start` instead?

Comment: @derHugo moving to Start, nothing changes. The size is already big enough (i can write manually the text), but changing his size to all screen it displays first two letters of the phrase. Very strange

Comment: And sure there is nothing disabling that component? Or maybe you are playing around with the `Time.timeScale` in which case it might also never finish the `WaitForSeconds` ...